# Casting a Nullable Decimal Dependency Property to an Int32 Failing

Tags: c#, uwp

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl TestDecimal="{Binding ViewModelTestDecimal}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public decimal? ViewModelTestDecimal { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug.TestControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestIntConversion}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestDecimal}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**TestControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug
{
    public sealed partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public int? TestIntConversion
        {
            get { return TestDecimal.HasValue ? Decimal.ToInt32(TestDecimal.Value) : 0; }
            set { TestDecimal = (decimal)value; }
        }        

        public decimal? TestDecimal
        {
            get { return (decimal?)GetValue(TestDecimalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestDecimalProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDecimalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestDecimal", typeof(object), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));


        public TestControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Use Case:**

I want to have a single dependency property to bind to for my consumer but in the view of this control, I have two different controls. One that shows the number as a decimal and one that shows it as an int.

**The Problem:**

I'm getting an exception on this line

`get { return TestDecimal.HasValue ? Decimal.ToInt32(TestDecimal.Value) : 0; }`

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]'.

When I change `Decimal.ToInt32(TestDecimal.Value)` to a property not backed by a nullable decimal dependency property, it works fine. This seems to be related directly to the dependency property

### UPDATE

If you'd like to see the bug for yourself, I've taken the time to abstract this out to a very basic working example

https://github.com/DotNetRussell/NullableDependencyPropertyCastBug

[image]

Comment: The only place you could get that exception is on `return (decimal?)GetValue(ValueProperty);`, which is being called in the first `Value` reference in `Value.Value`.

Comment: @madreflection so yes. I wasn't sure because when visual studio paused it displayed the context window over the line I posted but highlighted the line you pointed out

Comment: Enable stepping into properties and you'll get more granular stepping.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need the value as an `int` just for display purposes (why not just use `ToString("N0")` or the equivalent formatting routine in UWP). But basically, if you're going to use a Nullable, use nullable throughout, don't use `.Value` in some places. In other words, plan for null.

Comment: Try `(decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal(GetValue(ValueProperty))`

Comment: @juharr same exception same location

Comment: You haven't posted any code that would lead to that exception. Both calls to `SetValue()` use a `decimal` value, not an `int` value, so they can't be the place the value is getting set to an `int`. Most likely you've bound the `IntValue` property to some `int` source or target and that's updating it. But without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say. One option would be to use the `is` operator to check the type before casting, and cast to `int` before casting to `decimal` if you find that the object value is `int`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho have you pulled the code down in the github link that I posed at the end and run it? It literally is a working example, and certainly throws the exception https://i.imgur.com/dTEQmyJ.png

Comment: @PeterDuniho just so no one has to go to github I posted the full set of code above.

Comment: Please try to use `x:Bind` to replace `Binding` and remove  `DataContext = this;`

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I just put the bound property in the behind code to simplify this example. In the actual application it's bound to a view model so using x:bind wouldn't be accurate

Comment: So, you're saying that the behavior you're asking about, **doesn't happen if you don't use a `UserControl`**?

Comment: @PeterDuniho no, I'm saying the bug doesn't happen if I don't convert a property backed by a dependency property.

Comment: Then why does your so-called [mcve] have a `UserControl` in it?

Comment: @PeterDuniho because you wanted an example of what I was doing. So I created an example of what I'm doing. I'm not sure why there's so much confusion over this. The issue is clearly defined and I provided a working example of it as you requested.

Comment: What _I_ was asking for was a [mcve]. If there are things in the code you post that are not actually needed in order to reproduce the behavior, then the code is not **minimal**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not sure if UserControl is related or not. This is the setup I have. This is the minimal code that I think is required. I'm sorry if you don't think it's minimal enough but either way this is the best I can provide at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the issue was.

The problem was indeed the dependency property

**What is posted above**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDecimalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestDecimal", typeof(object), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

note the `PropertyMetaData` constructor, when you use a `0` in code without a type designation, C# will infer that the type you want is `Int32`. C# isn't smart enough to know to look at the dependency property to infer the actual type that you want.

In the above case, replacing the `0` with `null` in the `PropertyMetadata` constructor fixes the issue.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDecimalProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestDecimal", typeof(object), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: I always use new PropertyMetadata(default(theTypeHere), OnPropertyChanged) .

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy we actually had a team discussion after I found this to make `default(type)` the new team standard

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your converting the decimal to an INT and trying to store it in a nullable INT.
This should do it, this is my test code from a console app that absolutely works for both a null decimal and one with a value.

```
        decimal? Value = System.Convert.ToDecimal("3.3234");
        //decimal? Value = null;

        int? _intValue;
        if (Value.HasValue)
            _intValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(Value.Value);
```

Comment: same exception same location

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Updated my answer, this code was tested and works as expected. Although, the previous version also worked.

Comment: Your code doesn't match. Try it with a nullable decimal dependency property. Thats where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

The code below converts a **decimal** value to an **int** value, as its name suggests.

```
Decimal.ToInt32(Value.Value)
```

In order to further convert it to an **int?** I would do something like this:

```
int? _intValue= Value.HasValue ? (Decimal.ToInt32(Value.Value) as int?) : null;
```

- The code checks if there is a value for *Value* and, if so, it tries to convert it to an **int** type and then cast it to an **int?**. Otherwise it returns *null*;
- The usage of **as** keyword for casting is justified by the fact that if the cast fails, it simply assigns *null* to the *_intValue* variable;
- This is the preferred method over the direct cast (using `(int?)Decimal.ToInt32(Value.Value)`) because in the case that the casting is not working, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I did try this and it doesn't work. Same exception, same location

Comment: `set { SetValue(ValueProperty, (decimal)value); }` In this bit of code, shouldn't it be **(decimal?)** instead of **(decimal)**?

Comment: Nullable decimals can be set to decimals and also null